# Using Singleton to Make Data Available to All classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a AuthenticationController which checks a database to see if the credentials are valid. Once it has been validated, I create an instance of a class (see below) and store the relevant parts from the table.

AuthenticationController.cs

```
public class AuthenticationController : Controller
{
    private readonly IEmployeeDetails ED;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Login loginItem)
{
      ED.Employee_Number = (string)employeeDataTable.Rows[0]["Employee_Number"].ToString(); // crash because ED is null ?
```

I want to share this instantiated object with all my controllers for all my views.

What is the best way to do this? (class looks like this but with more fields)

```
public class EmployeeDetails : IEmployeeDetails
{
       public int EmployeeNumber {get; set;}
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSingleton<IEmployeeDetails, EmployeeDetails>();
     services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you make each controller inherit from a base controller?

Comment: I am afraid you will have to be a bit more specific.  There are a number of factors that can influence the answer. For instance, have all controllers been created when this happens? I suppose that one way would be to store the EmployeeDetail instance somewhere high up in a base view for instance. The controllers could access it there, or it could be passed to them when they are created.

Comment: How is your `AuthenticationController` implemented? Is it a middleware within the pipeline? If yes, you should add an `ClaimsIdentity`to the given `ClaimsPrincipal` holding all desired values as a `Claim`. Then every controller can check if the `User` property holds the desired values or your middleware could immediately return a 401 and no controller would see the request.

Comment: Register the `EmployeeDetails` type as a singleton using the built-in [dependency injection mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and then inject your controllers with it.

Comment: How would I create a Singleton. It's my first time. Do I need to create an Interface?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? You can use ASP.NET Identity which is created for this purpose. Please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I would rather use your approach but I've been directed to do this.

Answer (score 2):

you have to inject your service into the controller constructor like this:

```
public AuthenticationController(IEmployeeDetails ED){
this.ED = ED;
}
```

plus, try to use AddScoped instead of AddSingleton, Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests, Singleton objects are the same for every object and every request.

Comment: So if there are two users attempting to use my website. With a singleton approach, the data would be available from one user to the other? This doesn't seem right. I thought that Each session would share this data. So one user will not be able to see another users data.

Comment: if that's what you want, keep it Singleton.

Comment: I want each user having their own instance of EmployeeDetail (no sharing between users). I will change it to Scoped. Thanks for the information and education